# Limiting number of incorrect login attempts with timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

What is the correct way to let the user verify the captcha after 4 unsuccessfully login attempts within the last 15 minutes. I have got everything running fine but not timestamp part of the query. To be more specific it can display captcha after 4 failed attempts when user try to log in 5th time or so on, irrespective of whether 15min or 30min have passed...

```
 $query1 = "SELECT login_attempts from users WHERE email = '$email' AND last_login < NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE";
 $result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1) OR die(mysqli_error());  
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
 $fail = (int)$row['login_attempts'];
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a separate table for login attempts, with a foreign key to the users table on  your primary key field 'user_id' I would guess. Only needs to be a small table with user_id and timestamp,  then you can do a COUNT of attempts by user_id over a given interval. INSERTs are less taxing than UPDATEs; plus you'd have a full history of failed login attempts for a that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, You have to check if the 4th last unsuccessful login attempt is before 15 minutes.

For achieving this, you have to store the time-stamps of last four unsuccessful logins in the database.

1. Create a field called unsuccesful_login_timestamps as text or varchar with large size in your db. We will store the UNIX timestamps of last four unsuccessful logins in comma separated form in this field.
2. When a user attempts to login, implement the following logic


        If username and password is valid, let user login (You can clear the unsuccesful_login_timestamps field if login is succesful if you want). Else, run the following code.

   ```
   $last_login_string = {{ get unsuccesful_login_timestamps value for this user from database }}
   $last_login_string = update_last_login($last_login_string);
   $fourth_last_login = get_4th_last_login($last_login_string);
   $time_difference = time() - $fourth_last_login;

   {{Update unsuccesful_login_timestamps in db with $last_login_string}}

   if($time_difference <900){
       //show captcha
   }else{
       //no_need_for_captcha
   }
   //Method to update last 4 unsuccessful logins by removing
   // the last one from the starting and append the latest time in the end
   function update_last_login($last_login_string){ 
       $time_array = array();
       if(strlen($last_login_string) > 0){
           $time_array = explode(",",$last_login_string);
           $size = count($time_array);
           if($size ==0){ //first attempt
               $last_login_string = time();
           }else if($size == 4){ //>=4th attempt
               $time_array[4]=time();
               array_shift($time_array);
               $last_login_string = implode(",",$time_array);
           }else{ // >0, but <4 attempts
               $time_array[$size]=time();
               $last_login_string = implode(",",$time_array);
           }
           return $last_login_string;
       }else{
           return time();
       }
   }

   function get_4th_last_login($last_login_string){
       $time_array = array();
       $time_array = explode(",",$last_login_string);
       if($size !=4){
           $last_login_time time();
       }else{
           $last_login_time = $time_array[0];
       }
       return $last_login_time;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with MySQL myself, but `DATE_SUB` may work:

```
SELECT login_attempts from users WHERE email = '$email' AND last_login BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW()
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer is assuming that you are storing a timestamp (using `time()` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`) as the value of the `last_login` column in the `users` table.

What you can do is declare a `$time` variable using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` and do something like this:

```
$time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - 900; // Current time minus 900 seconds (15 minutes)
$query1 = "SELECT login_attempts from users WHERE email = '$email' AND last_login < $time";
```

If you want to change the time duration, just change the `900` to whatever value (in seconds) you want.

Comment: Than you @BryanLavinParmenter, you are correct, I had last_login as TIMESTAMP and it only recognises seconds hence it is working now....

Comment: sorry but it looks like I was too excited to check your answer thoroughly. My last_login was in timestamp format. Hence this logic seems not to be working.